# How to resolve 'RuntimeError: Trying to eval in EAGER mode' while using a custom learning rate?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, learning-rate

I am working on using a custom learning rate scheduler and I am running into the error RuntimeError: Trying to eval in EAGER mode while I am trying to do so.

I have made a function for calculating the Learning Rate for an epoch and I've used the LearningRateScheduler() given by TensorFlow for implementing the model.

Here's my code for the aforementioned problem:

Model Architecture:

```
model_learning_rate = models.Sequential()
model_learning_rate.add(Conv2D(16,kernel_size=5,activation='relu',input_shape=(64,64,1)))
model_learning_rate.add(MaxPool2D())
model_learning_rate.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_learning_rate.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=5,activation='relu'))
model_learning_rate.add(MaxPool2D())
model_learning_rate.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_learning_rate.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=5,activation='relu'))
model_learning_rate.add(MaxPool2D())
model_learning_rate.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_learning_rate.add(Flatten())
model_learning_rate.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model_learning_rate.add(Dense(62, activation='softmax'))
model_learning_rate.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Custom Learning Rate Function:

```
def lr_schedule(epoch, lr):
    """Learning Rate Schedule
    # Arguments
        epoch (int): The number of epochs
    # Returns
        lr (float32): learning rate
    """
    global K1, K2

    Kz = 0.  # max penultimate activation
    S = 0.
    
    sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
    max_wt = 0.
    for weight in model_learning_rate.weights:
        norm = np.linalg.norm(weight.eval(sess))
        if norm > max_wt:
            max_wt = norm
    
    for i in range((len(X_train) - 1) // batch_size + 1):
        start_i = i * batch_size
        end_i = start_i + batch_size
        xb = X_train[start_i:end_i]
        
        tmp = np.array(func([xb]))
        activ = np.linalg.norm(tmp)
        sq = np.linalg.norm(np.square(tmp))

        if sq > S:
            S = sq
        
        if activ > Kz:
            Kz = activ

    K_ = ((num_classes - 1) * Kz) / (num_classes * batch_size) #+ 1e-4 * max_wt
    S_ = (num_classes - 1) ** 2 / (num_classes * batch_size) ** 2 * S #+ 2e-4 * max_wt * ((num_classes - 1) * Kz) / (num_classes * batch_size)
    
    K1 = beta1 * K1 + (1 - beta1) * K_
    K2 = beta2 * K2 + (1 - beta2) * S_

    lr = (np.sqrt(K2) + K.epsilon()) / K1
    print('S =', S, ', K1 =', K1,', K2 =', K2, ', K_ =', K_, ', lr =', lr)
    lrs.append(lr)
    print('Epoch', epoch, 'LR =', lr)
    return lr
```

Using the learning Rate:

```
lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)
history_learning_rate = model_learning_rate.fit(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8), epochs = 30, steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / 8, validation_data = (X_test,y_test), callbacks=[lr_scheduler])
```

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try help you. Thanks!

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Like the dataset is mostly like the MNIST dataset, but the images are of a much larger size, which I have scaled down to 64x64 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try suppressing it with this after importing tensorflow:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```